# Updating serviceworker in React App - successfully updates - but on refresh shows old code still with new serviceworker?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, caching, service-worker

I'm trying to show the newest updates to my app when there is an update available.

The react app is a create-react-app and its hosted on S3 and uses AWS cloudfront for caching.

When I push updates the client doesn't see those updates unless they do a hard refresh, so I looked into updating the serviceworker.

First:

Cloudfront is set to cache time of 0. So it should not display any old code.

The headers in index.html

```
  <meta http-equiv="cache-control" content="max-age=0" />
```

I have registered the serviceworker in index.js on loading of the app and pass in a config to update the serviceworker if there are new changes:

```
import swConfig from "./swConfig";


serviceWorker.register(swConfig);
```

swConfig.js

```
export default {
  onUpdate: (registration) => {
    registration.waiting.postMessage("skipWaiting");
    registration.unregister().then(() => {
      let confirm = window.confirm(
        "New updates to the app - please close the tab and reload"
      );
      if (confirm) {
        window.location.reload(true);
      } else {
        alert("Please close this tab and reload the page");
        window.location.reload(true);
      }
    });
  },
  onSuccess: (registration) => {
    console.info("sw on success state");
  },
};
```

**What happens when there is a new update pushed to S3 and cloudfront is invalidated:**

1. User sees an alert to update the app.
2. App refreshes.
3. User sees NEW content on the homepage.
4. **If user refreshes - they see the OLD content again** (or if they come back to the page at a later point in time, even after closing the tabs)

What is causing the old content to be displayed?

I have a feeling its related to "skipWaiting".

If I remove  `registration.waiting.postMessage("skipWaiting");` then the page will refresh and the serviceworker will update - **but the user WON'T see the NEW content**